# UserListError.ADVERTISER_NOT_WHITELISTED_FOR_USING_UPLOADED_DATA @ operations

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

When executing https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201809/Remarketing/AddCrmBasedUserList.php file which throws UserListError.ADVERTISER_NOT_WHITELISTED_FOR_USING_UPLOADED_DATA @ operations error

Answer (score 2):

Could you confirm if the account you're trying to use is already
whitelisted? To clarify, you would need to whitelist the account when
creating a CrmBasedUserList through AdWordsUserListService. You may refer
to this blog

https://ads-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/update-to-customer-match-requirements.html

You can also contact your Google representative and have it whitelisted.